# How to trigger omnicomplete/auto-completion on keystrokes in INSERT mode?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, omnicomplete

VIM's omnicomplete autocompletion is not really working as expected.

Is there a way to make it smarter?  Like, to monitor the context of surround text?  (e.g. don't trigger if within comments or quotes)

I ask because I cannot get to a happy place since switching to Vim when compared to the autocomplete/IntelliSense in IDEs such as Visual Studio, IntelliJ, Sublime and Atom (I've used all of these for development in the past).

The basic goals to this question:

- Can Omnicomplete be triggered on A-Za-z keystrokes in INSERT mode?  I already have it being triggered via "." dot symbols.
- How to get Omnicomplete to insert the func's parameters?

I am new to Vim for a few months and desperately trying to get a smooth workflow.  But without a good autocomplete option, while forcing me to be more vigilant in learning the code I am trying to use, it is greatly slowly me down over other IDEs I've used in the past.

## Atom + Go-Plus

Let's examine my expectations with Atom + Go-Plus.

I have a func named `func generate(entropy chan<- uint64)` located elsewhere in another Go file in the same package.

When I type the letter `g` on line 22, I immediately get a prompt with everything that begins with g:

[image: Atom's autocomplete with Go-Plus]

As you can see, there are 3 options that immediately pop up (the first two I think are just code snippets).  I can use an arrow key to scroll down to either option.

If I select the 3rd option (or if I continue to type `gen` the field narrows down to only 1 option), and `press enter` Atom/Visual Studio/Sublime all fill out the details of the method for me:

[image: atom with go-plus autocompletion]

I did not type any of the above.  It was inserted and I can override the details, modify them, or just TAB off and continue typing.

## Vim + Vim-Go (really Omnicomplete)

Let's compare that with my current (maybe broken?) config of `omnicomplete`.  I have this in my .vimrc:

`set completeopt=longest,menuone`

Within vim, if I type `gen`, all I get is what seems to be my previously entered text that I typed elsewhere in this buffer (and only in this buffer, not in other buffers).  If I happen to misspell something, all I get the misspelled version I previously entered for the life that I have vim open.  This tells me there is no IntelliSense/autocomplete at work - just something monitoring the keystrokes I make:

[image: vim with omnicomplete and autocomplete not working]

As you can see, autocomplete isn't working as I type.  Though, this does come in handy with comments and strings in other places and I kind of like how vim remembers my free-text I type.

Not really sure what Vim option is enabling this; but, it is not autocompletion.

Now, I can press `CTRL-X + CTRL-O` to force autocompletion and get `generate()` to show up:

[image: vim with omnicomplete and autocomplete]

This is better; but, I would expect it to show me autocomplete options as I type: not requiring 3 additional keystrokes to make it happen.  That is a whole lot of C-x C-o happenings throughout a few hours of coding.

**Is there a way to have Vim monitor my keystrokes in INSERT mode and display autocomplete if there is a matching ctag or function?**  That may be the answer to this functionality.

## Autocomplete with Parameters

There is a 2nd problem with autocompletion with `omnicomplete` that I could overlook the C-x C-o requirement of the above if this worked: once I do select the method I want to autocomplete, it does not insert the parameters/fields for me.

Going back to the screenshot above, if I select that method, this is what I get:

[image: vim with vim-go autocomplete not fully completing]

Notice that **it does not insert** the func's paramters.  It does not match the 2nd picture posted above, where the autocomplete in Atom, Sublime, and Visual Studio all complete the method with parameters showing.

I have read the vim wikia and have tried various options with `set completeopt` without any viable alternative.

For example, `set completeopt+=preview` gives me the preview window after selecting:

[image]

Why giving me the parameters in a preview, it still does not autocomplete my `line 22` of code and is often a distraction (I often times disable it because I type far faster than having to stop and "look up" all the time).

It took a lot of tweaking of the config file to get the below working; but, I was able to get "dot" autocompletion to work.  So, there is some form of autocompletion working:

[image: vim and vim-go autocompletion with dot]

But again, it does not fill in the parameters once I select a function which is pretty annoying to have to type `ESC + back arrow + back arrow + : + GoDoc` just to see what it was: that's 10 character strokes to see what it was.

Sure, Atom, Sublime, and VS is much prettier when "dot autocompleting":

[image: atom and go-plus dot autocompletion]

(it is also better ordered by types, though I do have vim setup to remember the last used at the top so that helps).  But I don't care about pretty - I just want my parameters to show up when selecting with 'dot'.

Any advice in how to tweak my vim-go and related plugins would be very welcome as I'd prefer to stay with Vim over any IDEs.  Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I see that [the author of `vim-go`](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/pull/685) has worked on the parameters-completion part and got it working:

[image: autocompletion with parameters in vim-go]

Though, I can't seem to get it working on my install (still debugging it), I wanted to show others that it is indeed possible to have autocomplete with parameters being filled.

Comment: 1. Vim is a text editor, not an IDE. If you need/want IDE features, use an IDE. 2. Vim only does *manual* completion, not *auto* completion.

Comment: I'm not sure if it supports fully automatic completion, but [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) is a pretty robust IDE style completion plugin.

Comment: Fall 2017 and still the moral of the story is to just stop trying to make vim work like an IDE. Vim is a great text editor but sadly we need IDE to work efficiently. After going through THAT STEEP learning curve and trying out dozens of plugins, one gets a Vim that chokes on syntax highlighting a file containing few hundred LOC (read: real life code). Completion and intellisense only seems to work on carefully curated demos :(

Comment: For those who also come around, there is a code-completion engine for Vim [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can Omnicomplete be triggered on A-Za-z keystrokes in INSERT mode?

You can listen to `InsertCharPre` event and check what keys have been pressed.

```
function! OpenCompletion()
    if !pumvisible() && ((v:char >= 'a' && v:char <= 'z') || (v:char >= 'A' && v:char <= 'Z'))
        call feedkeys("\<C-x>\<C-o>", "n")
    endif
endfunction

autocmd InsertCharPre * call OpenCompletion()
```

Also you should `set completeopt+=menuone,noselect,noinsert` to avoid vim inserting completion text automatically. But keep in mind it is not common decision and you will probably have some issues. The one I have found is it breaks `cgn` command.

For further reading do `help InsertCharPre`, `help autocmd-events`, `help pumvisible()`, `help feedkeys()`.

> How to get Omnicomplete to insert the func's parameters?

I used sublime for a some years and it represents builtin functions (default vim omnicompletion) with snippets. So if you want parameters to be inserted into the buffer you need to:

1. Install snippet manager like **ultisnips**, **neosnippet**, **minisnip**, **xptemplate** or [others](https://vimawesome.com/?q=snippet).
2. Create a bunch of snippets or install from somewhere.
3. Make your completion system recognize preferred snippet manager (many completion managers recognize **ultisnips**).

If you change your mind in the way of using so called **preview** window you mentioned above here are some tips:

1. It is possible to show preview window at the bottom of the screen `set splitbelow`.
2. You can `set previewheight` option to change its size.
3. To automatically close window after completion is done `autocmd CompleteDone * pclose`.

For further reading do `help ins-completion` and `help preview-window`

Comment: I've been looking for a way to open the completion window on typing as I was getting inconsistent behaviour between Unix and Windows with the same plugins. Your `OpenCompletion` snippet did the job wonderfully. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! But it there some way to silence this? I'm getting `pattern not found` when there is nothing to complete. Kind of annoying to have this error sitting around all the time.

Comment: Try to set `setlocal shortmess+=c`. See `help shortmess` for explanation.

Comment: This is a great solution! It might even bump YCM out of my .vimrc! +1. I did find that this messed with the replay of my macros though (by making the cursor occasionally move down a line... which is no good when the final position of the cursor is important). I [managed to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70816950/14467607) by turning the off and on autocompletion when I replay a macro.

Comment: The reason I haven't marked this as an answer after all of these years is because it does not perform the intellisense that I was originally asking for in the (long-winded) OP.  As in, display *my* code/func when typing, not 100s or snippers pre-programmed (I have plenty of snippets I created).  Basically, what `CTRL-X + CTRL-O` does is what I want, with parameter completion.  Your answer is good (you've had my +10 for years).  However, it doesn't directly answer it.  Marking as answer as others have found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the answer by @Evgeniy to be almost perfect - but I did find that
when replaying macros, the cursor would sometimes drop down a line (which would
break the macro). I managed to solve it with the following functions and
autocmds:

```
set completeopt+=menuone,noselect,noinsert " don't insert text automatically
set pumheight=5 " keep the autocomplete suggestion menu small
set shortmess+=c " don't give ins-completion-menu messages

" if completion menu closed, and two non-spaces typed, call autocomplete
let s:insert_count = 0
function! OpenCompletion()
    if string(v:char) =~ ' '
        let s:insert_count = 0
    else                    
        let s:insert_count += 1
    endif
    if !pumvisible() && s:insert_count >= 2
        silent! call feedkeys("\<C-n>", "n")
    endif
endfunction

function! TurnOnAutoComplete()
    augroup autocomplete
        autocmd!
        autocmd InsertLeave let s:insert_count = 0
        autocmd InsertCharPre * silent! call OpenCompletion()
    augroup END
endfunction

function! TurnOffAutoComplete()
    augroup autocomplete
        autocmd!
    augroup END
endfunction

function! ReplayMacroWithoutAutoComplete()
    call TurnOffAutoComplete()
    let reg = getcharstr()
    execute "normal! @".reg
    call TurnOnAutoComplete()
endfunction

call TurnOnAutoComplete()

" don't let the above mess with replaying macros
nnoremap <silent> @ :call ReplayMacroWithoutAutoComplete()<CR>

" use tab for navigating the autocomplete menu
inoremap <expr> <TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"
inoremap <expr> <S-TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<TAB>"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

there are ways including triggering omnicompletion as answered by peers here. Other way is to use plugins. Several good ones are available and I find the quickest no frills basic pop up completion that you can trigger omnicomplete out of the box, are as follows below:

- https://github.com/maralla/completor.vim
- https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-mucomplete

if you are using `plug`, place following line in your `.vimrc`

```
Plug 'maralla/completor.vim'  " enables completion - https://github.com/maralla/completor.vim
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your screenshot is not autocompletion but instead just come tracking keystrokes.  I go into those details in my original questions along with the plugins you suggested as not the answer.

Comment: @eduncan911 i think the original question is to trigger omnicompletion. which is what my answer does. not keystrokes. completor for example triggers the default omnicompletion. Its a super fast way for people starting with vim to get this started.